# Adding new column based on multiple conditio

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have a `data` that looks like this:

```
< Id <- c(A,B,C,D,E)
< Father <- c(2,1,5,4,2)
< Mother <- c(1,3,3,5,1)
```

What I want is to add a new column say `parent` based on the higher value of father or mother. Basically:

```
< Id <- c(A,B,C,D,E)
< Father <- c(2,1,5,4,2)
< Mother <- c(1,3,3,5,1)
< Parent <- c(2,3,5,5,2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `pmax` to get the elementwise `max` of multiple columns

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Parent = pmax(Father, Mother))
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
df1$Parent <- with(df1, pmax(Father, Mother))
```

Or another option with `ifelse`

```
df1$Parent <- with(df1, ifelse(Father > Mother, Father, Mother))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Id, Father, Mother)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @akrun